# ArrayList<File> contains filename

Tags: android, arraylist, contains

I have a problem with an ArrayList (File in the above code). This arraylist is composed by files that are located into the sd. The problem is that I can have duplicates (the same image, but in different paths into the sd, so the same filename but different path) and I want to remove them. So I use this code:

```
ArrayList<File> removedDuplicates = new ArrayList<File>();

for (int i = 0; i < File.size(); i++) {
    if (!removedDuplicates.contains(File.get(i))) {
        removedDuplicates.add(File.get(i));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, I guess because contains() for a List of File looks at the filepath instead of at the filename. Is it true? How can I solve my problem? I also tried with:

```
ArrayList<File> removedDuplicates = new ArrayList<File>();

for (int i = 0; i < File.size(); i++) {
    if (!removedDuplicates.contains(File.get(i).getName())) {
        removedDuplicates.add(File.get(i));
    }
}
```

but still it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: As a suggestion maintain 2 array list one for file name and other for path+filename. add in array list of path+filename if array list file name does not contains file in at .

Comment: Rather, go in for a `Map<String, File>`. Will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of getName is String and the type of object in your ArrayList is File, so you're never going to get the same thing.

You want to compare the names inside the ArrayList.

```
for(File f : files){
    String fName = f.getName();
    boolean found = false;
    for(File f2 : removedDuplicates){
       if(f2.getName().equals(fName)){
           found = true;
           break;
       }
    }
    if(!found){
        removedDuplicates.add(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple.
PS: Tested Code

```
Map<String, File> removedDuplicatesMap = new HashMap<String, File>();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
        String filePath = files.get(i).getAbsolutePath();
        String filename = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(System
                .getProperty("file.separator")));
        removedDuplicatesMap.put(filename, files.get(i));
    }
    ArrayList<File> removedDuplicates = new ArrayList<File>(
            removedDuplicatesMap.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<File> removedDuplicates = new ArrayList<File>();

File temp;   
for (int i = 0; i < File.size(); i++) {
   temp=new File(File.get(i).getAbsolutePath());   
   if (!removedDuplicates.contains(temp)) {
         removedDuplicates.add(File.get(i));
   }
}
```